# Snap SVG : Fixed bottom and animate height only

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I need to animate the height of a rectangle in SVG with the bottom fixed. I am using Snap SVG library.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/k8aLeh82/) of what I have tried.

If the `y` parameter is not added, the rectangle's height animates to the top. So to fix the bottom, I have animated the `y` parameter too, but then I didn't get the bottom fixed.

Please share your thoughts to fix the bottom and animate the height only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

rect = s.rect(10, 5, 50, 100);
rect.attr({
    fill: '#fc0'
});
rect.animate({
    y:100,
    height: 5
}, 1500, mina.easein);
```

If you change the height from 100 to 5 you must change the y by 95 in the opposite direction for the bottom to appear fixed.